# Unicode Character U07AE not working in LibreOffice/Gedit

Tags: 17.10, language-support, input-language, unicode

When using 'Dhivehi' as a keyboard input source, unicode character U07AE does not work when typing on LibreOffice or Gedit.

The character is <kbd>o</kbd> on the keyboard. When this key is pressed nothing happens.

All the other keys (characters) work fine except for the one that should be given by pressing <kbd>o</kbd>. Even <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> Works. I also tried exchanging the mapping of the unicode to another key. Even with that, the unicode character did not work.

I have tried changing xkb/symbol mapping to a different key. But that didn't help.

With `xev` tool, the Unicode symbol is detected in the Terminal. But it does not work when tried elsewhere.

I can insert the character by typing the Unicode, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ U07AE. But to do this, I have to change language to English.

This issue came up on Ubuntu 17.10; in 16.04 it works as it should.

Comment: How do you want to enter it?

Comment: Using Libre or edit.

Comment: What keys would you like to use to type it in?

Comment: @Yamboy1 As 8fan wrote, "The Character is 'o' of the Keyboard", which means they should be able to type it by pressing the O key on their English keyboard.

Comment: @wjandrea: U+07AE is called THAANA OBOFILI. It is a non-spacing mark used in [Thaana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaana), a script used for writing the Maldivian language. It has nothing to do with U+004F LATIN LETTER O.

Comment: @alexP is right :)

Comment: @AlexP I understand that. My comment was just to clarify: OP is saying they should be able to press the O key on their keyboard (since it's an English layout), and a Thaana obofili will be typed (since it's mapped to the Dhivehi layout).

Comment: @AlexP See the [Dhivehi keyboard layout](http://www.typingtester.org/social/dhivehi.jpg). The obofili is on the O key.

Comment: @wjandrea in Dhivehi keyboard layout O and o are 2 different Character. Im able to use O but not o.

Comment: @8fan I'm using the capital letter "O" to refer to the key, not the character produced when you press it. So in that context, you're talking about Shift+O and O (with no modifiers).

Comment: So in an English layout, pressing O produces `o`, pressing Shift+O produces `O`.

Comment: @wjandrea yes. Additionally if I change the Unicode Character of <kbd>o</kbd> from xkbd/symbol/mv file, the new Character also works.

Answer (score 1):

just for the record, this is fixed by

```
sudo apt install ibus-m17n
```

reboot and you would get option to add "Divehi" phoenatic keyboard under regional and language settings.

works in ubuntu 19.04

Comment: I didn't see a "Divehi" keyboard available to install, but after changing "Keyboard input method system" to "XIM" it's working.