# Wrong keyboard input in Dhivehi language

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language, unicode

On Dhivehi input, when I press the <kbd>o</kbd> key, an unexpected character appears. The expected character is the Thaana obofili (U+7AE), and that's what the key mapping shows. But when I press the key, some Greek character (U+385) appears. And when any key is pressed or mouse is clicked after that, the character disappears. I checked the key mapping with `xmodmap -pke`, and the key mapping seems correct. I'm currently on Ubuntu 20.04, but it happened in Ubuntu 18.04 too. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode Character U07AE not working in LibreOffice/Gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978638/unicode-character-u07ae-not-working-in-libreoffice-gedit)

Comment: There is also [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1734034).

Comment: It kinda works..? I have to select another keyboard layout, which only works if I have the original Dhivehi layout enabled too. Otherwise it types in English. So I have to have both enabled. Even then, I can't type the character in Atom editor. It works in LibreOffice, Gedit and Firefox though